# Recycler View not displaying in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make an application where when i press a button it would open the fragment which contains a Recycler view where the data is retried from Firebase Firestore and added to an adapter. I've managed to connect the pieces together but the recycler view does not seem to be showing but the other components inside the fragments are.

Anyone able to find out what am I missing in the code or what I'm doing wrong?

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myReport = findViewById(R.id.myReport);
    publicReport = findViewById(R.id.publicReport);


    myReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myReportFragment();
        }
    });

    /*Opens separate fragment but similar code*/
    publicReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            publicReportFragment();
        }
    });

}


public void publicReportFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.report_fragments, new PublicReportFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public void myReportFragment() {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.report_fragments, new MyReportFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/publicReport"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="74dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="74dp"
            android:text="public report" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/myReport"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="67dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="67dp"
            android:text="public report"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/report_fragments"
            android:layout_below="@id/myReport"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MyReportFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_report, container, false);


    Query query = reportRef.whereEqualTo("reportByUserID","K2TPzSkIjvXCI2m1QGhyYr7qWpw1").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Report> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Report>()
            .setQuery(query, Report.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new ReportAdapter(options);

    myRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.myReportRecyclerView);
    myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

**fragment_my_report.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyReportFragment">

    <!--When button click the text view shows but recycler view doesnt*/-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MY REPORTS"
        />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myReportRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**ReportAdapter.java**

```
public class ReportAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Report, ReportAdapter.ReportHolder>{

    public ReportAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Report> options) {
        super(options);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportHolder reportHolder, int i, @NonNull Report report) {
        String seriousLvl = "";

        reportHolder.txtTitle.setText(report.getReportType());
        reportHolder.txtDescription.setText(report.getDescription());
        reportHolder.txtDate.setText(report.getDate());
        reportHolder.txtReportedBy.setText(report.getReportedBy());

        seriousLvl = report.getSeriousness();

        if(seriousLvl.equals("Low")){
            reportHolder.seriousness.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100,0,255,11));
        }else if(seriousLvl.equals("Medium")){
            reportHolder.seriousness.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100,255,220,0));
        }else if(seriousLvl.equals("High")){
            reportHolder.seriousness.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100,255,0,0));
        }else{
            Log.d("ERROR", "NEITHER: ");
        }

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReportHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_item,parent,false);

        return new ReportHolder(v);
    }

    class ReportHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtTitle,txtDescription,txtDate,txtReportedBy;
        CardView seriousness;

        public ReportHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            seriousness = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seriousness);
            txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
            txtDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
            txtDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_date);
            txtReportedBy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_report_by);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing `myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`

Comment: I think that the query is returning the data async, and your adapter is set but with 0 items. Please check this one also.

Comment: @RahulKhurana didn't work

Comment: you forgot to set `getItemCount()` method

Comment: I have added `@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return super.getItemCount();
    }` but it still didn't work

Answer (score 4):

I think you forgot to set size in your adapter:-

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return yourList.size();
    }
```

Comment: do i need to have a list? Cause I'm using FirestoreRecyclerOption which where i would include my "list" of data. Sorry if i may not make any sense I'm still fairly new

Comment: some time FirestoreRecyclerAdapter not working like that we want that's why create your custom adapter and send your list in constructor and do your work.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

As mentioned by @Sandeep Malik first I was missing `getItemCount()` function and second create a custom adapter to send data through the constructor. It may not be the most elegant way of dealing with the problem but it does solve the problem.

Here are the changes

**MyReportFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mReport = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_report, container, false);
    myRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.myReportRecyclerView);

    Task<QuerySnapshot> query = reportRef
            .whereEqualTo("reportedByUserID","K2TPzSkIjvXCI2m1QGhyYr7qWpw1")
            .orderBy("date",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots){
                        Report report = documentSnapshot.toObject(Report.class);
                        mReport.add(report);
                    }

                    adapter = new ReportsAdapter(getContext(),mReport);

                    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "onFailure: "+e.getMessage());
                }
            });
    return view;
}
```

**ReportsAdapter**

```
public class ReportsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportsAdapter.ReportHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Report> mReports;


    public ReportsAdapter(Context context, List<Report> reports){
        mContext = context;
        mReports = reports;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReportHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.note_item, parent, false);
        return new ReportHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportHolder holder, int position) {

        String seriousLvl = "";

        Report report = mReports.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(report.getReportType());
        holder.txtDescription.setText(report.getDescription());
        holder.txtDate.setText(report.getDate());
        holder.txtReportedBy.setText(report.getReportedBy());

        seriousLvl = report.getSeriousness();

        if (seriousLvl.equals("Low")) {
            holder.seriousness.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 0, 255, 11));
        } else if (seriousLvl.equals("Medium")) {
            holder.seriousness.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 220, 0));
        } else if (seriousLvl.equals("High")) {
            holder.seriousness.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 0, 0));
        } else {
            Log.d("ERROR", "NEITHER: ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mReports.size();
    }

    public class ReportHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView txtTitle, txtDescription, txtDate, txtReportedBy;
        CardView seriousness;


        public ReportHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            seriousness = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seriousness);
            txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
            txtDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
            txtDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_date);
            txtReportedBy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_report_by);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have added a custom adapter

Comment: @SandeepMalik yes I did