# Repopulate Different Data Onto RecyclerView Based On Button Click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 2 buttons `publicReport` and `myReport` and if i click on public reports it would get all the data from my my firebase where as if I click on myReport it would only get data based on the current login user. Currently I'm achieving this through have 2 fragments and displaying 2 recycler view which I believe is not very suitable. Is there any way perhaps in the adapter where I can repopulate different data based on the button clicks? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964999/recycler-view-not-displaying-in-fragment/) is a link to my previous post where I implemented fragments for the case

Here are some of the codes

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ReportAdapter mAdapter;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("Report");
    private List<Report> mReport;
    private Button publicReport,myReport;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        publicReport = findViewById(R.id.publicReport);
        myReport = findViewById(R.id.myReport);


        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mReport = new ArrayList<>();

        myReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                collectionReference.orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            Report report = documentSnapshot.toObject(Report.class);
                            mReport.add(report);
                        }

                        mAdapter = new ReportAdapter(getApplicationContext(),mReport);

                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }
                });


            }
        });

        publicReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //TODO: POPULATE ALL REPORT DATA
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ReportAdapter**

```
public class ReportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReportAdapter.ReportHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Report> mReports;

    public ReportAdapter(Context context, List<Report> reports){
        mContext = context;
        mReports = reports;
    }

    public void onRefreshAdapter(List<Report> reports){
        mReports = reports;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReportHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.report_item, parent, false);
        return new ReportHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReportHolder holder, int position) {
        String seriousLvl = "";

        Report report = mReports.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(report.getReportType());
        holder.txtDescription.setText(report.getDescription());
        holder.txtDate.setText(report.getDate());
        holder.txtReportedBy.setText(report.getReportedBy());

        seriousLvl = report.getSeriousness();

        if (seriousLvl.equals("Low")) {
            holder.seriousness.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 0, 255, 11));
        } else if (seriousLvl.equals("Medium")) {
            holder.seriousness.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 220, 0));
        } else if (seriousLvl.equals("High")) {
            holder.seriousness.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 255, 0, 0));
        } else {
            Log.d("ERROR", "NEITHER: ");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ReportHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView txtTitle, txtDescription, txtDate, txtReportedBy;
        CardView seriousness;

        public ReportHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            seriousness = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seriousness);
            txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
            txtDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
            txtDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_date);
            txtReportedBy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_report_by);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

1. Store your data in ArrayList
2. Create a method in recyclerview adapter like this

```
public void onRefreshAdapter(ArrayList<GetterSetterClass> yourList) {
                       global arraylist in adapter= yourList ;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

Call onRefreshAdapter() in your button click
```

Comment: Sorry but can you explain a little more detail? For instance where would i add the code which is responsible for getting specific data from firebase?

Comment: @DexterSiahTzeMing kindly share your adapter class code and fragment

Comment: I have decided to not use fragment instead to add the recycler view onto the activity layout. I have added the codes

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

As mentioned by @Murali Krishnan, i had to add the onRefreshAdapter method in my report adapter and when on my on click function i would first clear off the ArrayList then readd with new data.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    publicReport = findViewById(R.id.publicReport);
    myReport = findViewById(R.id.myReport);
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mReport = new ArrayList<>();

    myReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            collectionReference.orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Report report = documentSnapshot.toObject(Report.class);

                        mReport.clear();
                        mReport.add(report);

                    }

                    mAdapter = new ReportAdapter(MainActivity.this, mReport);
                    mAdapter.onRefreshAdapter(mReport);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
            });

        }
    });

    publicReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            collectionReference.whereEqualTo("reportedByUserID","K2TPzSkIjvXCI2m1QGhyYr7qWpw1").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Report report = documentSnapshot.toObject(Report.class);
                        mReport.clear();
                        mReport.add(report);

                    }

                    mAdapter = new ReportAdapter(MainActivity.this, mReport);
                    mAdapter.onRefreshAdapter(mReport);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**ReportAdapter**

```
public void onRefreshAdapter(List<Report> reports){
    mReports = reports;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to load both the data list in separate list at starting of the fragment and set the default list to the recyclerview adapter.

when user presses button try to change the data set of RecyclerView adapter by adding new function,

```
public changeDateSet(ArrayList<Objects> aDataList){
     mCurrentDataList = aDataList;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

On Every Button Click event you call this function with pre-loaded data sets so that it will update the GUI.

Important: After changing the data set of the adapter you have to do notifyDataSetChanged(); otherwise recyclerview will not update the gui.